# Calculating the limit of the "$\dfrac{volume}{area}$" ratio for a 2D function

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Let's assume that we have a well behaving, continuous function $f(x,y)$ defined on $\mathbb{R^2}$. The double integral $\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\int_{y_0}^{y_1}f(x,y)dxdy$ gives the volume of the space trapped between the rectangular region $[x_0,x_1]\times[y_0,y_1]$ and the function $f(x,y)$. I want to calculate the following ratio as a limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0)} \dfrac{\int_{x_0}^{x}\int_{y_0}^{y}f(x,y)dxdy}{(x-x_0)(y-y_0)}$$

This is the ratio between the volume of the space under the function and the rectangular area beneath the volume.

For a function of a single variable, this would be equivalent to $\lim_{x->0}\dfrac{\int_{x_0}^{x}f(x)dx}{x-x_0}$ which gives $f(x)$ if I am not mistaken; for a single variable function, this would be the limit of the ratio between the area under the function and the interval length beneath the area.

Is it possible to evaluate the two dimensional version of this limit? I do not how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible.  For "nice enough" functions, we can rewrite this limit as
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{1}{x-x_0}\left( 
\lim_{y \to y_0} \frac{1}{y-y_0}\int_{y_0}^y  \left(\int_{x_0}^x f(s,t)\,ds \right)dt
\right)
$$
Which we may evaluate using the fact (via the fundamental theorem of calculus) that
$$
\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{1}{x-x_0} \int_{x_0}^x g(t)\,dt = g(x_0)
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I knew that this was possible intuitively, but I lack the mathematical rigor. But how can we split a limit of two variables into two separate ones like you did? Is there a rule for that? Or is it something related with the "niceness" of the function?

Comment: In fact, we can say that
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (x_0,y_0))} f(x,y) = \lim_{x \to x_0} \lim_{y \to y_0} f(x,y)
$$
whenever the first limit exists.  The niceness of the functions is irrelevant.

Comment: Niceness is required for the fundamental theorem of calculus, though.

Comment: I am seeing this "iterated limit" notation for the first time. Does $\lim_{x \to x_0} \lim_{y \to y_0} f(x,y)$ mean the following: For each $x$, we calculate $\lim_{y \to y_0} f(x,y)$ and this happens to be a function $g(x)$. (Provided the limits exist). Then we calculate $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x)$. Is this definition correct?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$